# What is difference between in and on option at perspective filter

Tags: ffmpeg

What is difference between *in* and *on* option at [perspective](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#perspective) filter.

```
in
    Input frame count. 
on
    Output frame count.
```

Two commands same preview.

```
ffplay -f lavfi testsrc2 -vf perspective=print(in):0:W:0:0:H:W:H:0:0:0:eval=frame

ffplay -f lavfi testsrc2 -vf perspective=print(on):0:W:0:0:H:W:H:0:0:0:eval=frame
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point of time, nothing.

Timeline editing was introduced to the filter in April 2016. Along with dynamic expression evaluation mode, those two variables were introduced. But nothing's done with them except initialization. I suspect it's an oversight since the perspective filter takes one input and supplies one output. And the filter's job is to manipulate the spatial geometry of a frame - there's no temporal editing involved.